# How do I assign one task for multiple Spinners?

Tags: java

I am a new learner in Android Programming and now I am studying how to use spinner. With Button by using onClickListener, to assign one task for multiple buttons, I can use this form below

```
switch (v.getId()) {
   case (R.id.button1) :
       do something;
       break;
       ...
```

I wonder whether I can apply the same thing for spinner or not? Or because my way of applying is not proper. Here I have my code, at first I thought the transportation for data does not run properly, then I try to put a Toast to check and obviously there is no String assigned. I also tried with using directly spinner1, spinner2,... instead of parent but It didn't seem more optimistic.

```
private class Shoes implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    private boolean isFirst = false;

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        if (isFirst == false) {
            isFirst = true;
        }
        else {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case (R.id.spinner1) :
                    choosen_item[0] = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), choosen_item[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    bundle.putString("item1", choosen_item[0]);
                    break;
                case (R.id.spinner2) :
                    choosen_item[1] = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    bundle.putString("item2", choosen_item[1]);
                    break;
                case (R.id.spinner3) :
                    choosen_item[2] = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    bundle.putString("item3", choosen_item[2]);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```